# How to select customer names with maximum invoice value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables

```
Customers
----------------
ID  | Name 
----+-----------
123 | Name1
456 | Name2
789 | Name3
----------------


Invoices
------------------
ID  | Value
----+-------------
123 | 1000
456 | 500
789 | 1000
------------------
```

I want to select customer names with the maximum invoice value

Comment: Which result do you want for this sample data? Also, what if a customer has multiple invoices?

Comment: Do you want to get the top customer or you want to get a number of customers with invoice value sorted in descending order?

Comment: I want to get the customer names with the highest invoice value in this case the highest invoice value is 1000  and the result should be name1 and name3

Comment: it doesn't matter if the customer has multiple invoices or not if one of his invoices equal to the highest invoice value, his name should be returned

Comment: Did you get your answer ? Could you tell the MySQL version you are using ?

Comment: @MohammedAhmedMohammed . . . It is really rude to change a question after has been answered -- and in such a way as to invalidate answers.

Comment: No, I didn't get the answer yet, SQL version is SQL 2016

Comment: I didn't change the question BTW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test against the max value

```
select c.name , i.value
from customers c
join invoices i on i.id = c.id
where i.value = (select max(value) from invoices);

+-------+-------+
| name  | value |
+-------+-------+
| Name1 |  1000 |
| Name3 |  1000 |
+-------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: It did work thank you

Answer (score 0):

we can get results with subquery also.
Use [] Brackets with value and Name. Because this is a reserved keyword in the SQL server

```
SELECT C.ID, C.[Name], I.[Value]
FROM Customers C WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN (
       SELECT TOP 1 ID, [Value]
       FROM Invoices WITH(NOLOCK)
       ORDER BY [Value] DESC
      ) AS I
ON C.ID = I.ID
```

Comment: This is a sqlserver answer to a mysql question - the code is not transportable and you may attract downvotes as a result

Comment: He already mentioned for SQL and my SQL. please check definition and his comment @P.Salmon

Comment: Please review the sql tag - it does not imply the OP is using sqlserver - that;s why tags exist to more precisely identify the sql dialect the question is about. If OP had wanted sqlserver there is a tag for that.